# MySQL - Flush Memory after loading files

Tags: mysql, performance, memory

I am loading a great amount of data which are in CSV files using LOAD FILE command. It is working fine and after loading that files, it executes some data transformation...

The problem is that, after loading for example 12 files (400 MB each one), mysql process consumes almost all memory available, it is not flushing, and so, the machine slow down, and I need to restart mysql to continue to load data files.

MySQL 8.0.17

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

- Added Store Procedure

  ```sql
  BEGIN
  DECLARE sequenceid INT;

  DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;


  START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT INTO filenamedt (filename, filedate, fileinitialid) VALUES (CAfilename, now(), (SELECT MAX(imp_sequence_id) + 1 FROM imp_siscori_sequence));

  INSERT INTO imp (select imp, ordem, CONCAT(TRIM(data),'01')) FROM temp_imp);

  INSERT INTO imp_data (imp_id, unid_comerc, incoterm) (SELECT imp_id, TRIM(unidadeComercial),  TRIM(incoterm),  TRIM(natInformacao) FROM temp_imp );

  INSERT INTO imp_description (imp_id, imp_description) (SELECT imp_id, TRIM(descricaoProduto) FROM temp_imp);

  UPDATE imp_sequence SET imp_sequence_id  = (SELECT MAX(imp_id) + 1 FROM temp_imp_siscori);

  TRUNCATE TABLE temp_imp;

  SET @m = (SELECT MAX(imp_sequence_id) + 1 FROM imp_sequence); 

  SET @s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE temp_imp AUTO_INCREMENT=', @m);

  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;

  EXECUTE stmt1;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

  IF `_rollback` THEN

      ROLLBACK;

  ELSE

      COMMIT;

  END IF;
  ```

Comment: which engine do you use ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI InnoDB

Comment: After loading 12 files, run and post complete TEXT results of MySQLTuner for analysis.  Continue shutdown, restart and load 12 more.

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM?  Are there indexes on the tables?  Are you LOADing into a single table, or 12 empty tables?

Comment: We can not propose any ideas with this limited information.  Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @RickJames I load each file into a unique temporary data table, and from this table, I trigger a store procedure which transform all data and so, insert this data into 3 different tables. Servar has 8 GB RAM, it is db.t3.large (RDS) machine. There are indexes on that tables, in one of them it is a FULLTEXT index. I load one file each time.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I posted at https://pastebin.com/dPns18xY Thank you for your help

Comment: @RickJames, I did it, thank you very much, but I would like to understand for what reason, memory ram is still going away while I am loading files into database. I need to load more than 100 files 400MB each,

Comment: @Gustavo_Oliveira - What tool is saying that "all memory is going away"?  `top` somewhat lies.  Is the amount of "swap" going up?

Comment: @Gustavo_Oliveira  We still NEED - Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report after 10 files have been LOADED - your GS is for 2271 seconds - not enough to be useful
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
from AWS support team, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Gustavo_Oliveira  How much RAM on the server and # cores?

Comment: @WilsonHauck 2 cores, 8 GB RAM, 200 GB SSD

Comment: Any chance of your posting the MySQLTuner complete report and the other items requested 12 hours ago?

Comment: I have same issue trying to load a huge MyISAM, https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/269071/109971

Comment: I did it! Thanks a lot... Now, when I am loading files, sometimes, the store procedure which deals with that almost freezes with "Waiting for handler commit" status. Do you figure out what is going on? I will edit post in order to show you the store procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using MyISAM for anything (and you should not), then change `key_buffer_size 999997440` to only 10M.  That is a wasted gigabyte.

Also, this seems quite large for your 8GB of RAM:  `tmp_table_size  268435456`.  Lower it to 16M.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your AWS RDS Performance group

```
innodb_flush_neighbors=2  # from 0 to speed reduction of innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty of 11,890
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 to expedite LOADing data
read_rnd_buffer_size=64K  # from 512K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 16,317
```

Both of Rick James suggestions of 2020-06-12 22:40 will conserve RAM.

For additional suggestions view my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.